# VCRUNTIME140.dll is missing?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, dll

I use windows 7 x64 and i need vcruntime140.dll in my program. But it's missing. 
I reinstall Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015 x86 and x64 and restart pc but stil dll missing.(Also installed all version of Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio xxxx)

I thought, it's because of windows update but finally i looked at system32 folder and vcruntime140.dll is in there.

How can i insert that dll in system path and is there a solution? Or how can i fix this problem?

Comment: There are two, one for x64 programs and one for x86 programs (aka Win32, aka 32-bit).  Crystal ball says that you need it for a 32-bit program and you installed the wrong flavor.

Answer (score 0):

Try repairing this distribution on uninstall or modify programs.

Sometimes x64 dll's are put in system32 folder wich is why this error occur, you can also use dependency walker to check that.

Answer (score 0):

install Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015 or repair &
just go to SysWOW64 & sys32 if find vcruntime140.dll jus copy & past & rename a copy to VCRUNTIME140.dll "yes Big letter"